# telprompt on Android and Windows Phone

Tags: android, url, windows-phone-8, windows-phone

I am aware that `tel:0012345` works on every platform to make an immediate call. But on iPhone there is also `telprompt:0012345` which only pre-dials the phone number for the user but doesn't immediately starts the phone call.

Is there something similar like `telprompt` available on Android and Windows Phone available too?

Comment: For Windows Phone, do you mean predial a phone number through C# code?

Comment: Talking about links/URLs (for ex. href in HTML).

Answer (score -2, accepted):

`telprompt` isn't documented anywhere but seem to work on Windows Phone and Android too.

Comment: telprompt: does not work for UWP or Android. I've tested Edge, Chrome and WebView for Android.

Comment: telprompt is not working on android for me